# Event AgendaCalendarView

Tags: android

I 'm using the library **[AgendaCalendarView](https://github.com/Tibolte/AgendaCalendarView)**

I have the `calendarEvent` inside the `onEventSelected()` method:

```
public void onEventSelected ( CalendarEvent calendarEvent ) { }
```

This event returns a string with the title, but what I want you to also return the ID of the event to use it in another activity.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can use provide a [mcve] and what you expect to happen please?

Comment: El evento devuelve una cadena con el titulo, pero lo que quiero es que también devuelva el ID del evento para poder usarlo en otra actividad.

Comment: @Jeanpierechevarria, cual es la url de tu librería, agregala al otro sitio porque este grillo es un poco metiche y te va a poner puntos menos jeje, saludos!

Comment: com.github.tibolte:agendacalendarview:1.0.4,
https://github.com/Tibolte/AgendaCalendarView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of id inside `onEventSelected()` method  in this way:

```
@Override
    public void onEventSelected(CalendarEvent calendarEvent) {
     Log.d("MainActivity", "id del evento: " + calendarEvent.getId());
    }
```

In fact, inside this method you can get the described values of title and day.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class that extends the BaseCalendarEvent and in this class create your own id as in my scenario case number is unique.
Cast the CalendarEvent into your own class then you will be able to access all public method.

```
@Override
    public void onEventSelected(CalendarEvent event) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onEventSelected: " + ((MyCaseCalendarEvent) event).getCaseNumber());
    }
```